# Radiobuttons inside preferences category?

Tags: android

How to add radio button in preferences category?

I am trying to add radioButton in preferences Category but I am not able to do like that.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Do you mean ListPreference?

Comment: maybe this could be a solution, but I´ve never tried it. But it is possible, You have to do Your own custom preference. Here the link for Java source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/f5d3e74ecc2b973941d8adbe40c6b23094b5abb7/src/com/android/settings/location/RadioButtonPreference.java

Comment: ...and here for xml source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/f5d3e74ecc2b973941d8adbe40c6b23094b5abb7/res/layout/preference_widget_radiobutton.xml

Comment: no  not for list preferences...instead of listpreferences i  want radio button inside preferences catagory.....(thanks for your anaswer  sir)